# Using md-primary on div

Tags: angular-material

I would like to use the primary style which has been defined with  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette on a div, like this:

```
<div class="md-primary">
```

However this does not work (no styling is applied).

Are there any way I can use the styles (colors) definied as "md-primary" on any element (a div in this case) without duplicating the style to a css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the primary is not exactly a color, but a pallete, if is a button there is pre loaded values for it `<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">My Button</md-button>`, but in a div you need to specify like: `md-colors="::{background: 'palletename-primary-800'}"` and in the app config define the pallet

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('palletname')
     .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
     .accentPalette('lime')
     .warnPalette('red');
$mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('palletname');
```